# Weird CSS width and height on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css

I've encountered a problem with width and height property on iOS while on Chrome on PC it's working fine.

Working fine on Chrome:

[image: Working fine on PC Chrome]

on iOS, same code:

[image: Shouldn't be like that]

SCSS Code:

```
.zoom-controls {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
  @include flexbox(column, center);

  button {
    @include flex(0);
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    border: none;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    line-height: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(#000, 0.5);
    color: #FFF;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 36px;
    outline: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    @include box-sizing(border-box);

    .up {
      line-height: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

`flexbox` and `flex` custom mixins:

```
@mixin flex($grow, $shrink: 1, $basis: auto)
{
  -webkit-box-flex: $grow;
  -moz-box-flex: $grow;
  -webkit-flex: $grow $shrink $basis;
  -ms-flex: $grow $shrink $basis;
  box-flex: $grow $shrink $basis;
  flex: $grow $shrink $basis;
}


@mixin flexbox($direction, $justify, $wrap: nowrap)
{
  @include display-flex();
  @include flex-flow($direction, $wrap);
  @include justify-content($justify);
}
```

And finally the HTML of those controls:

```
<div class="zoom-controls">
  <button class="up" hm-tap="add()">+</button>
  <button class="down" hm-tap="subtract()">-</button>
</div>
```

It definitely looks like there is some width problems, although i haven't got idea what could cause that.

Comment: It looks like your button is still flexing. Does using `@include flex(0, 0)` on it help?

Comment: @onetrickpony no, it doesn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this

```
@mixin flex($grow, $shrink: 1, $basis: auto)
{
  -webkit-box-flex: $grow;
  -moz-box-flex: $grow;
  -webkit-flex: $grow $shrink $basis;
  -ms-flex: $grow $shrink $basis;
  box-flex: $grow $shrink $basis;
  flex: $grow $shrink $basis;
}
```

into this

```
@mixin flex($grow, $shrink, $basis: auto)
{
  -webkit-box-flex: $grow;
  -moz-box-flex: $grow;
  -webkit-flex: $grow $shrink $basis;
  -ms-flex: $grow $shrink $basis;
  box-flex: $grow $shrink $basis;
  flex: $grow $shrink $basis;
}
```

i think this is causing the problem

```
$shrink: 1
```

Comment: While I pass 0 as a `shrink` parameters it still doesn't help.

Comment: it should be `@mixin flex($grow, $shrink, $basis: auto)`

Comment: It can't be like that, cause it's ruining other things in my app

Comment: give me the url, i will ix it for you

Comment: It's a fault of `font-size`.